# Update a Google Sheets spreadsheet with information from a website when button is clicked

Tags: selenium, events, selenium-webdriver, automation

I place a lot of bets using Betfair, and I keep track of these in a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

Manually placing the information for each bet takes a long time.

I was wondering if there was a way of collecting the bet information from the Betfair website when I click Betfair's 'Place Bets' button (see image), and writing a script to add this information to my Google Sheets spreadsheet i.e. using Selenium Webdriver.

I suppose what I am asking is whether there is a way of calling my own script for a specific event on a webpage.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Betfair]

Comment: You can create an extension for your browser and add a functionality to the Place Bets button with it. Also to parse the bet info from the website and post it to your Google Sheet.

Comment: @MarkDavydov I think this is what I'm looking for, are there any other pointers you could give me towards writing a chrome extension say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First step:**
Learn to post stuff to Google Sheet, 
You can try watching this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxqfwfQi0jk)

**Second step:**
Learn the basics of Google Chrome Extension making, you don't need much just the basics.
[Try This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-QToZcV84Q)

Third step:
Parse the webpage and find the div for bet price and div for button.

Fourth step:
Using that information integrate it in JS script for your extension

Profit.
Good luck.